# z-index issue with background image and image parent tag

Tags: css

i've some problem with the z-index property:
This is the code:

```
<div id="sidebarCont">
<div id="avatarCont" class="mask">
    <img id="" class="" src="img.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#avatarCont{
overflow:hidden;
height:160px;
width:160px;
margin:0px auto;
background:url('../img/mask.png') no-repeat;
position:relative;
z-index:70;
```

}

```
#avatarCont img{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:50;
```

}

i whant to have a mask on the image, someone have ideas to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the mask on top of the image. Make the image the background of the outer container and the mask a background on an inner container. The browser will render the outer container first (the image) and then it will render the inner container (the mask) on top. If you are trying to do alpha transparency, then the web cannot do that for you.

Structure:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="mask"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image, .mask {
    height:160px;
    width:160px;
}

.image {
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:70;
}

.mask {
    background:url('img.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer, i need to have on the firts div a background image that cover the other div with another img background, the first container have a z-index higger value.

Comment: Then my answer is "you can't". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:after` pseudo element, in this way you have a mask after the container: http://jsfiddle.net/7Fx7W/2/